# php creating separate user/admin login

Tags: php, admin

I'm trying to set up different accesses using user and admin but i can't figure out how to make them seem different, i tried setting the tinyint on database where 1 is admin and 0 is user, but i don't think i did it right. (u found the code for it somewhere else) so if there's a better way, help would be most appreciated. thank you in advance.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Homeowners Association</title>

</head>


<?php
    if ($_SESSION['validUser'] == "yes")                
    //is this already a valid user?
    {

//turn off PHP and turn on HTML
?>                          
        <h1>Display Events Admin Options</h1>
        <p><a href="insertEvent.html">Input New Events</a></p>
        <p><a href="selectEventsProtected.php">List of Events</a></p>
        <p><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></p>

<?php   //turn off HTML and PHP
    }
    else
    {
        if (isset($_POST['submitLogin']) )          
        //Was this page called from a submitted form?
        {
            $inUsername = $_POST['loginUsername'];  
            //pull the username from the form
            $inPassword = $_POST['loginPassword'];  
            //pull the password from the form

            include ('dbConnect.php');              
            //Connect to the database

            $sql = "SELECT * FROM homeowners WHERE username = '" . $inUsername . "' AND password = '" . $inPassword . "'";              
            //this SQL command will only work if BOTH the username and password on the table

            $result = mysqli_query($link,$sql) or die("SQL Error " . mysqli_error($link) . "<p>SQL String: $sql</p>" );

            if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1 )     
            //If this is a valid user there should be ONE row only
            {
                $_SESSION['validUser'] = "yes";         
                //this is a valid user so set your SESSION variable

//turn off PHP and begin HTML
?>
                <h1>Display Events Admin Options</h1>
                <p><a href="insertEvent.html">Input New Event</a></p>
                <p><a href="selectEventsProtected.php">List of Events</a></p>
                <p><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></p>  

<?php //turn off HTML and turn on PHP                               
            }
            else                                    
            //This is an invalid user not in the database
            {
                echo "<h3>Invalid username or password.  Please try again.</h3>";   //sets error message
                //display login form again with the error message.

//turn off PHP and begin HTML
?>

                <form method="post" name="login" action="login.php" >
                  <p>Username: <input name="loginUsername" type="text" /></p>
                  <p>Password: <input name="loginPassword" type="password" /></p>
                  <p><input name="submitLogin" value="Login" type="submit" /> <input name="" type="reset" />&nbsp;</p>
                </form>

<?php //turn off HTML and turn on PHP
            }//end of checking for a valid user
        }//end of checking for a submitted page
        else    //This page was not submitted so the user needs  to se the sign on form to continue
        {
            //display the login form in the area below

//turn off PHP and begin HTML           
?>
            <h1>Login to access website</h1>
            <form method="post" name="loginForm" action="login.php">
                <p>Username: <input name="loginUsername" type="text" /></p>
                <p>Password: <input name="loginPassword" type="password" /></p>
                <p><input name="submitLogin" value="Login" type="submit" /> <input name="" type="reset" />&nbsp;</p>
            </form>

<?php //turn off HTML and turn on PHP
        }//ends if statement to check for form submit
    }//end if checking for a valid user

//turn off PHP and begin HTML
?>

</body>
</html>
```

I tried using:

```
$query = mysqli_query("SELECT type FROM homeowners WHERE username = '$user'");
$gettype = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
if($gettype["type"] == 0){
echo("user");
}
elseif($gettype["type"] == 1){
echo("admin");
}
```

but I don't know enough about tinyint (which i have set to type)

Answer (score 1):

no problem if you use tinyint, but i prefer enum to determine user access because it direcly shows the user access. not just number and I must remember again what mean of 1,2,3, or whatever.

to show the admin page or user page, you just need one more `$_SESSION` variable to store user access.

```
include 'dbConnect.php';

$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT type FROM homeowners WHERE username = '$user'");
$gettype = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
if($gettype["type"] == 0){
    $_SESSION["userAccess"] = "user"
}
elseif($gettype["type"] == 1){
    $_SESSION["userAccess"] = "admin"
}
```

and add this to your if

```
if ($_SESSION["validUser"] == "yes") {
    if($_SESSION["userAccess"] == "admin") {
        //show admin stuff or admin page
    } elseif ($_SESSION["userAccess"] == "user") {
        //show user stuff or user page
    }
}
```

dont forget to use `session_start()` in top of your code in `login.php` and other file if you want to use `$_SESSION`

---

**UPDATE**

see my updated answer.
you made mistake in `mysqli_query()`, that method need 2 parameter like this:

```
$query = mysqli_query($con, "YOUR_QUERY");
```

`$con` is from YOUR_DB_CONFIG_FILE.php. In your case dbConnect.php

Comment: is this answer using tinyint or the enum (which i can't get to use cause the data base says there's an error everytime i try)?

Comment: this answer is using tinyint, can you post your database table?

Comment: i didn't know how so i posted it to my server as a jpg
http://felicyiamcclelland.com/introphp/homeowners/images/server.jpg